# Are you comfortable with who(m) he is?

Tags: pronouns, objects, subjects, relative-clauses

> - Are you comfortable with him? (*correct*)
> - Are you comfortable with whom he is? (*??*)
> - You're comfortable with whom he is. (*??*)
> - Are you comfortable with who he is? (*??*)
> - You're comfortable with whom? (*correct*)

Why does adding *he is* change the usage of *who/whom*?  I understand that the *is* is reflective and takes the nominative case, but my brain is not "computing" because I've never seen anything following *with* ever be nominative...until now.

Please enlighten me.

PS: There are no tags for 'nominative' or 'dative' or likely any of the other cases.

Comment: Related: [Can I Help Who's Next](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6923/can-i-help-whos-next) and [“It is they who lied” or “it is them who lied?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17636/it-is-they-who-lied-or-it-is-them-who-lied)

Comment: I see... subclauses, eh?

Comment: I think the technical term is "a total mess that confuses everyone".

Comment: @RegDwight, indeed! I spend far too long thinking about this particular problem. It gives me sleepless nights!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

<strike>*Whom*</strike> would be **wrong** in your example; it should be *who*. The reason is that a **relative pronoun** functions as part of the relative clause, not of the main clause. Don't let the question mark fool you: *who* is a relative pronoun here, not an interrogative one.

> Are you comfortable with [the person]
>   ***who*** he is?

This shows the structure of your sentence a little better. *The person*, the hypothetical antecedent of the relative clause *who he is*, is left out or enclosed in the relative pronoun *who*. In any case, *who* is part of the relative clause, not the main clause. That is why we should be looking at its function within the subordinate clause: it is subject (or subject complement) in *who he is*; therefore we need **who**, not *whom*.

It does not matter at all what function the (explicit or implicit) antecedent has in the main clause:

> I fear him ***who*** gave me life.
>
> I fear him ***whom*** I have wronged.
>
> He ***who*** gave me life frightens
>   me.
>
> He ***whom*** I have wronged frightens
>   me.

---

If *who/whom* is used as an **interrogative pronoun**, i.e. not introducing a subordinate clause, it is its function in the main clause that matters:

> **Who** are you?
>
> **Whom** do you see?

---

Note that *who* is now more
frequent than *whom* in any case, and is
accepted by most wherever traditionalists would have *whom* as explained above.

Answer (score 5):

“Who he is” is just a noun phrase. As such, it cannot take any further inflection, no matter whether it’s included as a subclause:

> Are you comfortable with who he is?
> Are you comfortable with him?
>
> You are comfortable with who he is.
> You are comfortable with him.

Just like a phrase with *whom*, such as “whom he loves”, doesn’t change in the same context:

> Are you comfortable with whom he loves?
> Are you comfortable with her?
>
> You are comfortable with whom he loves.
> You are comfortable with her.

Use of *who* or *whom* is entirely dependent on the contents of the clause, *not* the phrase in which the clause appears.

Comment: You do not know how often seeing this wrong in printed books really irks me.  Somehow, the writers and editors alike were all playing hooky on whatever day the mandatory lesson about such things was presented back in school.

Comment: 'There seems to be no agreed unitary rule governing the inflection of _who_ where it functions as subject of a clause to which it is not adjacent' (Geoffrey Pullum). For more, see here http://chronicle.com/blogs/linguafranca/2012/11/30/one-rule-to-ring-them-all/

Comment: @BarrieEngland: The motivating example of that article doesn’t convince me. I read “some contend” in “whom some contend was autistic” as parenthetical. Even if I didn’t, *whom* would seem obviously wrong because “some contend *he* was autistic”, not “some contend \**him* was”.