# "Whom" is right but I've never EVER heard anyone say "whom" out loud

Tags: questions, objects, whom

For example:

"Whom hit you?"

"Whom should I pick?"

Maybe no one has enough time to think about this in quick, everyday conversation?

Comment: “Whom hit you” is ***not*** right.

Comment: This question is based on a false premise.

Comment: The following question is relevant: most people seldom use whom, and it's almost never used in speech. Use "who" unless you're writing in formal contexts or for a pedant. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/397966/why-do-so-many-people-struggle-with-who-and-whom

Comment: I've said "whom" out loud, often.

Answer (score 2):

"Whom hit you?" is not correct.

"Who" is used to replace a *subject*.

Ex: "**Who** hit you?" is the answer for "**I/you/he/she/it** hit me."

"Whom" is used to replace an *object*.

Ex: "**Whom** did you hit?" is the answer for "Did you hit **me/you/him/her/it**?"

Comment: In your first example, I think you mixed up the question and answer. In your second example, both sentences are questions, even though you say that one is the answer for the other.