# May I please help who(m)ever is next

Tags: pronouns, whom, syntactic-analysis, whoever-vs-whomever

I am bringing up a rather pedantic point here, but, one that has me completely stumped.  This is going to require some serious grammar knowledge.

I was in a line at a shop today and the teenager at the counter actually said "May I please help **whomever** is next."  As a matter of conversational English, I dare say, this construction borders on pretentious.  But, on deeper thought, it might be fine in formal English since the subject of the dependent clause should typically agree with the main clause.

But, then I found the [following post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6923/can-i-help-whos-next#comment165075_6924) by Edwin Ashworth on this site regarding the issue:

> If one wants to be pedantic, the correct version uses whoever rather
>   than whomever in this construction as, though the accusative is
>   required to agree with the main clause (Can I help John? Can I help
>   him? Can I help him who is next? NOT *Can I help he who is next? - see
>   Fowler), the compound lexeme whoever fulfils a dual accusative
>   (relating to the main clause)/nominative (relating to the relative
>   clause) role. Whomever fulfils a double accusative role (Treat
>   whomever the acid came into contact with).

I followed Mr. Ashworth's explnation until he started making distinctions between dual and double accusatives (which I didn't think existed in English).  If anyone could offer a clearer explanation, I would be apprecative.  Thanks.

Comment: To clarify Edwin's post: By _dual role_ he means that the noun fills both an accusative role in the main clause and a nominative role in the subordinate. By _double accusative_ he means that it consistently fills an accusative role in both clauses.

Comment: See also [this blog post](http://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.com/2007/10/can-i-help-whos-next.html) and [this blog post](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/002690.html).

Comment: By *dual role*, he means that "who(m)ever" appears both as the object of the sentence "May I please help who(m)ever" and the subject of "who(m)ever is next". Because "who(m)ever" is used as the subject of at last one of these clauses, you use "whoever". If it were an object in both clauses, you are supposed to use "whomever".

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand the context of what Mr. Ashworth meant, i.e. object of both clauses vs. subject of the last clause, etc.  What I am wondering is where his rule comes from, i.e. that "whoever fulfils a dual accusative" and "[w]homever fulfils a double accusative role[.]"  I have just never heard this rule stated before, is it a formal prescriptive "rule" of grammar taken from another language or is it just an observation about how we speak?

My general feeling about this is simple:  when in doubt, use whoever.

Comment: It is a 'rule' given by [Fowler](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Z4HI0RQIDK0C&pg=PA727&lpg=PA727&dq=whoever+727+whomever&source=bl&ots=wcH3-A0iFQ&sig=VsbWEFkwOs61ASqCBAO-ZfRFPSA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Ss-lUszSAuqv7AaY54DQDA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=whoever%20727%20whomever&f=false). And explained more deeply by [BillJ](http://www.englishforums.com/English/WhomeverVWhoever/bbchhx/post.htm).

Answer (score 2):

You only have a problem if you parse the sentence as:

> May I please help whomever [is next].

If you parse it correctly as:

> May I please help [whoever is next],

with *whoever* as subject of the dependent clause, then it is clear why *whoever* is right.

Comment: How does this square with [my earlier comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121073/may-i-please-help-whomever-is-next#comment248897_121078)? Why is it correct to parse it the way you say is correct and not the other way?

Comment: I believe the points are (1) if you can parse it two ways, and one is nominative, you use "whoever", (2) if you can parse it two ways, and both are accusative, you use "whomever", (3) if you can parse it two ways, you must use "who(m)ever" and not just "who(m)".

Comment: Andrew, I agree that it would have to be _May I please help him who is next_, where _who_ functions as the subject of the dependent clause. We could use _whomever_, if we wished to be formal, when _whomever_ is the object of the dependent clause. _I will help whomever the manager selected._ Follett in _Modern American Usage_ discusses a sentence similar to the OP's and states that _the object of the main clause is not 'who(m)ever', but the whole clause of which the subject is necessarily 'whoever'_. This is indeed a tricky issue!

Comment: Thank you Shoe, your citation to Follett (and the explanation) pretty much settles this question for me.

Answer (score 1):

The question between *who* and *whom* has been treated several times on EL&U. In my mind the following link provides the best answers.
[What’s the rule for using “who” and “whom” correctly?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56/whats-the-rule-for-using-who-and-whom-correctly).

It's not such serious grammar knowledge as you fear. It can appear to be intimidating only because instances of whom, whomever, whom self, whom selves, have practically become extinct. People feel embarrassed whenever they hear or read these pronouns and feel they ought to know how to use these words in order to appear more educated. And perhaps in the case of the teenager shop assistant, who believed he was acting courteously (although it does sound affected).

> *May I please help whomever is next.

If we substitute "whomever" with the subject pronouns *she or he who is next* i.e. *anyone*, and joined the expression with a "that" clause, we would have the following sentence.

> May I please help *she or he/anyone that* is next.

Substituting *she or he* with the object pronouns, *her or him* would lead to an erroneous construction. We **don't** say: "*Me* is next"; "*him* is next", "*her* is next" "*us* are next"etc.. We should, however, say "*I (that) am* next", "*you (that) are* next", "*she (that) is* next" and so forth.

> *May I please help *her or him* that is next. (incorrect)

*Who* is used to substitute the subject in the main clause, in this case; she OR he, and by tagging *ever* onto *who* we understand the meaning to be; *anyone*.

Thus we arrive at this grammatically correct sentence.

> May I please help **whoever** is next.

(If I had been in the shop assistant's position I would have said) Someone else's offer of assistance might have been:

> May I please help the next customer.

A grammatically correct sentence with the added bonus of not sounding *pretentious* in the slightest.

Tip: Never use *whom*, *whomever*, *to whom* etc. if you're not 100% sure of getting it right.

EDIT: Many thanks to @Bradd Szonye whose comments made me realize that the question of "whomever is next" vs "whoever is next" is indeed a much more complex grammatical one than I initially thought. I wish to qualify myself as not being a linguist but someone who strives to make the "jargon" more accessible, not only for her private students but for her own benefit too.

Comment: While I think you're correct, I'm not sure that substituting he/him for who/whom is helpful for native speakers in this case. The underlying confusion is that people aren't sure whether to analyze the sentence as “(May I please help him) that is next” or “May I please help (he that is next).” Is _whom_ the object of _help,_ or is _who_ the subject of _is_? My instincts actually tell me that *“(May I please help him) (who is next)” is correct, even though I'm pretty sure it's wrong when I think it through.

Comment: @BraddSzonye  But *whoever* means "anyone" as in: May I help anyone next? That surely is a correct sentence, isn't it? If my answer is wrong, please tell me. But I don't think it is... Maybe I have over-simplified the matter. "May I please help whomever is next" just doesn't sound right.

Comment: I think you _are_ correct. However, it's hard to follow your reasoning because your clarifying example, “May I please help she and he (which one = anyone) that is next,” _looks_ incorrect. There's too much noise in the middle of the key phrase, “she that is next,” so instead the eye focuses on the awkward “May I please **help she**....” I recommend dropping the extra words (and especially the parentheses) breaking up the key phrase.

Comment: "He who is next" is an entire idea. If that is used as an object (say, of *help*) it becomes *him who is next*. On that basis, *whomever* **would** be correct.

Comment: @Mari-LouA That's much better, although I would simplify it even further and also emphasize the verb: “May I please help **she who is** next.” By the way, I really appreciate your contributions here – you're an asset to the site.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I'm torn. “Help him who is next” does sound natural to me, but I'm swayed by Edwin's reasoning that _he/him_ should agree with the subordinate clause and not the main clause.

Comment: @Bradd: Mari-Lou's answer is arguable (either way), but "May I please help she who is next" is plainly mistaken.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Don't delete! It might not be correct, but I don't think it's obviously incorrect either. Let the voting system work for you.

Comment: Fowler gives an example of the form

(*)“Do not follow he who breaks the law.” 

saying (I’m sure correctly) that the correct version is 

“Do not follow him who breaks the law.”    Concerning _whoever_ and _whomever_, BillJ (see above for link) says [amended slightly]: "I must thank whoever gave me this gift" is a fused relative construction.  
"Whoever" is called a 'fused' relative word because the antecedent and the relative word are fused together instead of being expressed separately as in simpler constructions....

Comment: ..."Whoever" is thus simultaneously head of the NP in the matrix sentence [cf "I must thank _your brother_"] **and** subject of the relative clause; the meaning is comparable with "the person who gave me this gift". Since the non-fused "who" is subject of this simpler construction, it follows that "whoever, not *whomever, must likewise be the correct fused relative word. Fused "whomever" would be strictly correct in, for example, "Invite whomever you like".