# When he first entered the classroom no one knew who/whom/whoever/whomever he was?

Tags: whom, who, whoever-vs-whomever

I am unable to understand which one is the correct?

Comment: Always use _who_; don't use any of the other ones. Even native speakers don't understand how to use them and they're dying out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Can I help who's next?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6923/can-i-help-whos-next)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The choice between *who[ever]/whom[ever]* comes down to the role of the relative pronoun **in the subordinate clause**. In this case, it will be nominative rather than oblique since *who* is linked to *he* by *was.*

Now, for *whoever* vs *who, whoever* implies an indefiniteness which isn't here so the correct phrase would be “When he first entered the classroom no one knew who he was.”